# Wordpress in Java environments (Resin+Quercus) without any additional code tweak?

Tags: java, wordpress, resin, caucho

There are some threads here about Resin/Quercus being used for Wordpress. I just want to confirm that once Quercus is installed, Wordpress will work just as-is, with .php file extensions and all? And all the usual URL Rewriting etc will work too in permalinks? Or will we need to do some manual and additional adjustments? (http://caucho.com/resin-4.0/admin/http-rewrite.xtp)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, wordpress works on Resin 4.0.x for us without modification. Although, you will probably want some rewrite rules in the WEB-INF/resin-web.xml for the "pretty" URL mapping.

Ours looks something like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://caucho.com/ns/resin"
         xmlns:resin="urn:java:com.caucho.resin">

  <!-- pass through all actual files to the standard dispatch -->
  <resin:Dispatch regexp="\.">
    <resin:IfFileExists/>
  </resin:Dispatch>

  <!-- pass through all php files to the standard dispatch -->
  <resin:Dispatch regexp="\.php"/>

  <!-- rewrite everything else to be /index.php/foo... -->
  <resin:Forward regexp="^" target="/index.php"/>

</web-app>
```